# Can't mount/format internal hard drive

Tags: 13.04, mount, hard-drive

I've been trying to use this guide to install a permanently mounted hard drive to store media on:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive

So far I've come up with next to nothing.

BIOS detects the hard drive. If I put in `sudo lshw -C disk` I get this:

> milo@Dante:~$ sudo lshw -C disk   *-disk
>
> ```
>    description: ATA Disk
>    product: KINGSTON SV300S3
>    physical id: 0.0.0
>    bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
>    logical name: /dev/sda
>    version: 520A
>    serial: 50026B723C03ED66
>    size: 111GiB (120GB)
>    capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
>    configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=8c17e47b-ba42-4724-bc20-cc1cc2f22b83 sectorsize=512   *-cdrom
>    description: DVD-RAM writer
>    product: DRW-24F1ST   a
>    vendor: ASUS
>    physical id: 0.0.0
>    bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
>    logical name: /dev/cdrom
>    logical name: /dev/sr0
>    logical name: /media/milo/disk
>    version: 1.00
>    capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
>    configuration: ansiversion=5 mount.fstype=udf mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=77,iocharset=utf8
> ```
>
> state=mounted status=nodisc   *-disk
>
> ```
>    description: ATA Disk
>    product: WDC WD10EZRX-00L
>    vendor: Western Digital
>    physical id: 0.0.0
>    bus info: scsi@5:0.0.0
>    logical name: /dev/sdb
>    version: 01.0
>    serial: WD-WCC4J2417140
>    size: 931GiB (1TB)
>    capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
>    configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=4096 signature=2f65c4e4
> ```

So ubuntu detects the drive (last one).

I used `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb` to make a single partition. That seemed to be ok and rerunning it now there is a partition showing on the drive.

However when I run this line to format the drive: `sudo mkfs -t fat32 /dev/sdb`

I get this error:

> milo@Dante:~$ sudo mkfs -t fat32 /dev/sdb1
>
> mkfs.fat32: No such file or directory

So now the drive can't be found anymore?

`sudo fdisk -l` gives this (excluding other hard drives):

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes 81 heads, 63
sectors/track, 382818 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors Units =
sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2f65c4e4

 Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
 /dev/sdb1            2048  1953525167   976761560   83  Linux
```

Can anyone help as I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1` in this case.